# Dropping a subset of variables with similar names

Tags: loops, foreach, stata

I have to import and alter a large set of csv files. At some point in this process I want to use the following code

```
    local vlist materialcost* costofemployees* city country 

    foreach v in vlist{
        capture drop  `v'
    }
```

However, locals don't allow an open-ended description like `materialcost*`
Alternatively, if I try

```
    foreach v of var materialcost* costofemployees* city country {
        capture drop  `v'
    }
```

I run into a problem because it cannot always find a variable with `materialcost` in the name, raising an error.

So I want Stata to `drop` all variables that start with `materialcost` if they are actually present in the data.

Comment: `materialcost*` doesn't pick up all variables with `materialcost` in their names, just those starting that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the statement that locals don't allow an open-ended description like `materialcost*` is incorrect both factually and in principle.

I just did it in Stata:

```
. local vlist materialcost* costofemployees* city country

. di "`vlist'"
materialcost* costofemployees* city country
```

So, the assignment to a local can and does work in practice. The principle is that locals are just containers for text and have no idea about being fussy on what that text might be (or mean), beyond a length limit not biting here, or usually.

The reason you said that may be that this didn't do what you wanted.

```
foreach v in vlist {
   capture drop  `v'
}
```

That syntax is legal, but not the way to get `foreach` to work through the contents of the local just defined. That loop boils down to

```
capture drop vlist
```

which will do nothing unless `vlist` is a variable name in your dataset.

Your main problem is this. If you say

```
foreach v of var materialcost* costofemployees* city country {
```

then it's essential that what follows the `var` keyword is in fact a variable list and `foreach` will throw you out without entering the loop if that is not so. It doesn't ignore exceptions. The `capture` inside the loop can't help; Stata never gets that far. However, my guess is that

```
foreach v in materialcost* costofemployees* city country {
    capture drop  `v'
}
```

should work for you as (a) you don't make a claim that may be wrong about what variables may exist and (b) `capture` does the work of catching any error that `drop` will raise if such variables don't exist.

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough explanation. My initial statement was indeed incorrect. When I tried to display the local myself I forgot the " " leading to my wrong conclusion.